# if condition is true redirect to logout and display session message?

Tags: php, mysql

hi im trying to put an if statement that says after login if the users account is banned then redirect to logout.php which logs the user out but i also want to display a session message after this happens. can this be done im trying to do the following but its only redirecting the user to logout and loggin them out, not displaying the session message.

please can someone show me where im going wrong thanks:

```
<? if (logged_in()) { ?> 
     <?
    $account_banned = account_banned();
    while ($banned = mysql_fetch_array($account_banned)) 


     if ($banned['account_banned'] == '1')  {
         $_SESSION['banned']="<div class=\"infobox-noprofile\"><strong>Account Banned</strong> - We could not log you in because your account has been banned. If you need to talk to us about this please email <a href=\"mailto:support@playtimeboys.com\">Support@PlaytimeBoys.com.</a></div><div class=\"infobox-close12\"></div>"; 

          redirect_to("logout.php");  


     ?>

     <? } }?>
```

in logout.php:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['banned']))
   echo $_SESSION['banned'];
    unset($_SESSION['banned']);

?>
```

Comment: What does `redirect_to` do?

Comment: you are missing session_start(); in the first page

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `session_start();` in the first file. And where is the logout processing? The person remains logged in (at least if he was in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Please don't save that kind of values inside session variables, instead do this:

first file:

```
<?php if (logged_in()) { 
        $account_banned = account_banned();
        while ($banned = mysql_fetch_array($account_banned)) 


         if ($banned['account_banned'] == '1')  {
             $_SESSION['banned']= true; 

              redirect_to("logout.php");  
         } 
       }
?>
```

logout.php

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['banned'])):?>
    <div class="infobox-noprofile"><strong>Account Banned</strong> - We could not log you in because your account has been banned. If you need to talk to us about this please email <a href="mailto:support@playtimeboys.com">Support@PlaytimeBoys.com.</a></div><div class="infobox-close12"></div>

<?php endif; 
 unset($_SESSION['banned']);
?>
```